# How to set NavigationView with AppBarConfiguration?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer, android-navigation

I'm new at navigation, my start destination in navigation component is not the same with my top destination so I used `AppBarConfiguration` to use a custom top destination but when I want to set NavigationView with `navController` using `NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController)` for setting the navigation component with drawer Items, but the app do not recognize my custom top destination when I press an Item in navigation drawer, navigate to a different fragment and press back button to navigate back to the top destination. It shows me the start destination but I want to see the custom top destination 
this is them main activity code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.NavDestination
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI
import com.example.android.pass.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

        val toolbar= binding.toolbar
        drawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
        navController = this.findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        navController
            .addOnDestinationChangedListener { nc: NavController, nd: NavDestination, args: Bundle? ->
                if (nd.id == R.id.accountListFragment) {
                drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED)
                } else {
                    drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)
                }
            }

        val topLevelDestinations = setOf(R.id.accountListFragment)
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration.Builder(topLevelDestinations)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawerLayout)
            .build()
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController)
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar,navController,appBarConfiguration)
    }
    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController,appBarConfiguration)
    }
}
```

and this is my drawer menu with two Items with the same id with the fragments I want to navigate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/aboutFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/question"
        android:title="About" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/settings"
        android:title="settings" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer, instead of using the following code to set `navigationView` with `navController`:
    `NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController)`
I used following code in the main activity:

```java
binding.navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.about_item -> navController.navigate(R.id.aboutFramgent)
        R.id.settings_item -> navController.navigate(R.id.settingsFramgent)
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Use this :**

```java
AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration =
        new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph()).build();
```

**instead of :**

```java
appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration.Builder(topLevelDestinations)
```

Comment: so how am I supposed to add my top destination if I remove this line of code:                                                      `appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration.Builder(topLevelDestinations)`